# tfs autobuild format to overwrite not increment

Tags: tfs

I am trying to have the TFS build process deploy a C# executable to a remote location and overwrite the existing executable there. How can I do this? If I set the build definition `Build Number Format` to `$(BuildDefinitionName)` then I get the error:

`TF42064: The build number '...' already exists for build definition`

**UPDATE**

It's TFS 2010 so I've asked for an upgrade to TFS 2015 or later. The application is deployed by using the default build template shared below:

[image]

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? How did you deploy your application? Could you share your build steps? Did you try to clean the target folder?

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT thanks, please see inline. As for cleaning the target I suppose we could manually delete the target before deployments... but I want TFS to do that for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's suggested upgrade your TFS 2010 to TFS 2015 or new versions, with new build systems in new TFS, it will be much easier to delete a target folder.

In TFS 2010, you could customize your TFS build template by adding InvokeProcess activity to invoke a command line/shell, and run a script to delete folders/files.